# Why can't I write to 0th element of string in C++?

Tags: c++, string

Here is a code which emits ""

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string k= "";
    k[0] = 'k';
    cout << k;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downvotes are most likely because the answer is easy to look up, yet the question was asked anyway.

Comment: The definition of easy is bit shaky. The answers here really stir up the discussion around interface issue and non-intuitive nature of std::string. The question is about seamless modification of the string which is not allowed here (contrary to allowed by += and push_back)

Comment: Easy in terms of the Standard explicitly saying Undefined Behaviour, but the Standard's a <expletive deleted> to read and find stuff in until you've worked through it a few times, so I'll give just about anyone a pass on that. Of the big two reference sites, cppreference is explicit, but cplusplus is wishy-washy, saying just "don't do this." This is why cplusplus has a negative reputation 'round these parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `k` has 0 elements. You're accessing it's first element. Assigning to it yields undefined behavior.

You can change it by initializing it with different size, i.e.:

```
string k = " ";
k[0] = 'k'; // ok
```

or

```
string k(1, 0);
k[0] = 'k'; // ok
```

or you can append the character:

```
k.push_back('k');
```

There's also the method [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) which performs bounds checking. If you call it with an invalid index (i.e. `k.at(0) = 'k'` in your example), it'll throw `std::out_of_range`.

Comment: Doesn't `k` have one element, which is `0`? The beyond-bounds access occurs when cout tries to read to the "end" of the string.

Comment: Realistically it does. But as far as the *interface* is concerned - it is empty.

Comment: What do you mean? I believe a string constant in C has a number of elements precisely equal to 1 + the number of characters in the source code.

Comment: @jtbandes are you aware that this is a C++ question? The size of this string is precisely 0.

Comment: Yes this is interface issue. Ideally, I should be able to write seamlessly if I just declare the string. I think I would make habit of using += and push_back

Comment: In that case look up the [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) method.

Answer (score 2):

`string k = "";` means you have string `k` that is empty with size 0.

You can verify this using `k.empty()`.
This is equivalent to,

```
bool empty() const { return this->size() == 0; }
```

So, what you are trying to do is, accessing the first element of the empty string which will yield Undefined Behavior. The link tells about the out-of-bound-index Undefined Behavior. Not on `string`, though.